# Can't get result with file_exists()

Tags: php

I've been trying to delete a .json file with php on my site, and can't get it to work.  It seems I can't get the path to the file right, or it's invisible.  So I thought I'd check with file_exists(), and no matter what I try, I cannot get the system to see a file that is on my server.

the json folder exists in this path
/mytheme/assets/js/geofences/1069.json

The php is being run from this path
/mytheme/inc/filelookingforjson.php

I have tried "../assets/js.." to send path pointer up one level using relative path...

I have tried absolute filepaths. and it's behaving like the file isn't there.  Is there some htaccess or some other thing i need to do on  a wordpress site?  Permissions on the geofences folder are set to read, writeable etc...   the code below sends me an email saying there is no file.  I'm sure I have the path wrong,  if i can get this correct than i can work on the unlink...  thank you for any input.

```
$file = '/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/js/geofences/1069.json';

    if(file_exists($file)){
    mail("me@email.com","file exists","file name is there");    
    } else {me@email.com","file does not exist found","file name is 
 not there");
}
```

Comment: Starting a path with `/` will make it an absolute path from the file systems root folder. (and I doubt you have a folder called `wp-content` in the root). Try: `$file = __DIR__ . '/../assets/js/geofences/1069.json';` and see if that works.

Comment: thank you for taking the time on this... I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The issue

If the folder structure is:

```
mytheme/
  inc/
    filelookingforjson.php
  assets/
    js/
      geofences/
        1069.json
```

then the path to the json file from the PHP file would be:

```
../assets/js/geofences/1069.json
```

However, considering that your PHP file most likely gets included by other PHP files, the path will be relative from the first accessed PHP file.

### Why is this?

Imagine this file structure:

```
index.php
folder/
   foo.php
   subfolder/
      bar.php
assets/
    hello.txt
```

Let's say that you want to read the file `hello.txt` in the file `bar.php`, then the relative path to `hello.txt` would be `../../assets/hello.txt`. This would work if you run the file `bar.php` directly.

#### The gotcha

The "gotcha" is when you're *not* accessing `bar.php` directly.

Let's now say that `index.php` includes `foo.php` and `foo.php` includes `bar.php`.

If you run `index.php`, the relative path in `bar.php` won't work anymore since it isn't relative from the first accessed PHP file in the include chain, which is `index.php`.

This does make sense if you think of `include` and `require` as a "copy/paste". PHP "copys" the code from the included file and "pastes" it into the file that does the including.

***Note:** this is of course a simplification of how it actually works*

### Solution

The magic constant `__DIR__`.

If you add that before your relative path, PHP will replace it with the absolute path to the file it was written in.

The code:

```
$file = __DIR__ . '/../../assets/hello.txt';
```

will be read by PHP as:

```
$file = '/folder/subfolder/../../assets/hello.txt';
```

Now it won't matter what file includes `bar.php`since the path will stay absolute.

The same thing goes when you're trying to include files using relative paths.

On a real server, the absolute path would probably look something like `/path/from/the/file-systems/root/folder/assets/hello.txt`.

Comment: Magnus, that is THE BEST explanation of the file path options I've read in two years.  I really appreciate you taking the time to explain in such detail. :)

Comment: Both notes above gave me the answer i needed, thank you!  The file exists, now I can kill it! :)