# "File not found" When running on heroku, but it works on local

Tags: php, heroku, filepath

I want to include a file that is in a parent folder in my php code using:

```
include('../defines.php');
```

However when I deploy to heroku from CLI and run my php file it gives me this error.

> PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '../defines.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/app/.heroku/php/lib/php') in /app/workers/test.php on line 2

If I run locally from my installed Wamp 3.1.4 server it run fines without issues.
I can make it work if I remove the `../?  from the path. But that seems wrong.
Another way I've found on github is doing

```
include __DIR__ . '/../defines.php';
```

But i think doing it that way would be using absolute, not relative path.

Is there something i'm missing?

```php
<?php
    include('../defines.php');
?>
```

Folder tree:

```
www/
    defines.php
    workers/
        test.php
```

Comment: Using `__DIR__` is a good practice. The `__DIR__` contains the absolute path to the file itself, where `../` will be relative from the top most file in the include chain (which means that the path will differ depending on where the file that's including this file is located). I wrote an answer about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55313007/2453432

Comment: Thanks, your answer really helped me understanding how __DIR__ works and why using it is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

It's depending how you classified your folder. 
Maybe you can try this :

```
require("/../yourFolder.php");
```

Comment: Wouldn't `/../yourFolder.php` suggest that you want to read the file `yourFolder.php` that's located one level _above_ the root folder of the complete file system? Where ever that would be :-o

Comment: It's the folder above basically

Comment: Since `/` is the top most folder (the root folder of the FS), then `/../` would mean a folder above that, which doesn't really make sense. You can't really go up one level from the root-folder. If you try it you might end up in Narnia or something (which, imho, would be kind of cool). If you just want to go up one level, it's: `../`, like the OP already have.

Comment: I didn't see your model
I think you can only do this: require("define.php");