# warning in php:Failed to open stream:no such file /directory in

Tags: php, mysql

I want this errors.php file to get included in my registeration form and the login form as well but as soon as I include it a warning pops on the registeration page saying failed to open stream:no such file / directory in

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Registeration.css">
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="signin">
         <form action="register.php" method="post">
        <?php include('errors.php'); ?> //warning oocurs here
        <h2>Sign Up !!!</h2>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required 
        name="username">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" required 
        name="email">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required 
        name="password_1">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required 
        name="password_2">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="reg_user">
        <h4>Already have an account?<a href="login.php">Login here</a></h4>
    </form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get result with file\_exists()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312721/cant-get-result-with-file-exists) - The question might not be 100% the same, but the answer applies here too.

Comment: What does this have to do with mysql?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using relative links ("css/registration"), if the file can't be found try adding a base tag to set the default path to your server.

```
<base href="http://www.website.com/include/">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is well explanatory that php is not able to include mentioned file
This usually occurs when we are not having file in PHP `include_path`. we can check `include_path` using `phpinfo()`. 
For your issue to solve it, please place `error.php` in `include_path` or in same directory in which your include script belongs