# Import php class from file

Tags: php

I am using `PHP 7.3.5` and I have two files, class `Foo()`, which is in the directory `./db/models` and my `main.php`, which is in the root of the project.

```
<?php

use Goutte\Client;

class Foo
{

    function getHello()
    {
       echo "Hello world!<br>";
    }


}
```

My `main.php` file looks the following:

```
<?php

include("./db/models/Foo.php");

$foo = new Foo;

$foo->getHello();
```

However, I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Foo' not found in C:\Users\Desktop\Code\test-project\main.php:5

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: does the include throw any warnings? Replace with require and see if you fatal error

Comment: I don't see why this would fail. Is that the exact code you have? There's no namespace declaration in `Foo.php`-file?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ^^ pos 404 error (under the hood) on that include is my hunch

Comment: @treyBake - Might be. If they are hiding warnings, then it make sense.

Comment: When including files, it's a good idea to use `__DIR__` to get the absolute path to the file you're in. If just do `include 'db/...';` it will load the file relative from the top most file (usually the index.php file). Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312721/cant-get-result-with-file-exists/55313007#55313007) that explains it in more detail.

Comment: I would also recommend making sure that you're using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` while you develop so you make sure you see all warnings as well. The error reporting level can also be set in your php.ini-file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
include("db/models/Foo.php");
```

Since your db folder is inside route you can simple access it like that.

You don't need the ./ to move one step before cause your main is already in the root. You need to move inside your nested folders to reach the `Foo.php`

Since you did not provide the full tree i assumed that your path to Foo.php is:

```
C:\Users\Desktop\Code\test-project\db\models\Foo.php
```

Comment: Thx. How can I then load the class?

Comment: Like you did. Your code should work from there. just use : `$foo = new Foo();` and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

./db is your hidden directory ?? If yes this can cause issue to loading files. Please verify directory