# Error while including class from anthor file in php

Tags: php

I want to include a class from file own.php but I am not able to include it as it giving me error as  require(class.own.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory .

I tried all the options i.e include, require, require_once but then also it showing me a error.
include("class/own.php");

own.php

```
<?php 
   class own{
    public function title(){
       $title = $_POST['title'];
       echo $title;
    }
  }
?>
```

display.php

```
include("class/own.php");

$obj = new own;
$obj->title();
```

Comment: what is your directory structure?

Comment: Can you please format your question, as it is a little bit hard to understand it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get result with file\_exists()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312721/cant-get-result-with-file-exists) - Look at the answer on that question. It's about how to reference paths to other files in relation to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I think the two files are in the same path (directory), so you are including wrong path. It might be `include("own.php");`

Considering the following directory structure.

```
|directory
    display.php
    own.php
```

**display.php**

```
<?php
   include("own.php");

   $obj = new own;
   $obj->title();
?>
```

Comment: I think the two files are in the same path, so you are including wrong path :) if you have doubt you clear in comments before ans.

Answer (score 0):

Your directory structure should be like this

```
display.php
class/own.php
```

Then try to include

```
include("class/own.php");
```

The use

```
$obj = new own(); OR $obj = new \own();
$obj->title();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<?php
class own {
    function title() {
        $this->model = $_POST['title'];
    }
}

// create an object
$test = new own();

// show object properties
echo $test->model;
?>
```

Comment: Some more explanation of why OP should *use this* would be helpful.  All you seem to be suggesting is including everything in one file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing PHP. To include the file the following code may help

`include (__DIR__)."/own.php";`